# PHPMail loses newline when string is 31 or more chars

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have code in a website's Contact page that assembles the user's entries and puts them in the body of an email. It's a series of lines like this:

```
$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\r\n";
$email_message .= "Address: ".clean_string($address)."\r\n";
$email_message .= "City: ".clean_string($city)."\r\n";
$email_message .= "State: ".clean_string($state)."\r\n";
$email_message .= "Zip: ".clean_string($zip)."\r\n";
```

clean_string is a function that removes a few things that would mess this up. Here's the code:

```
function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}
```

Near the end of this code, I recently added a new line to include a new item, for which people might write something longish.

```
$email_message .= "Purpose: ".clean_string($purpose)."\r\n";
```

I'm finding that if the user enters 31 or more characters, the "\r\n" for that line and subsequent lines has no effect and all those lines run together. With 30 characters, all looks right, but with 31, it's messed up.

I assuming I'm hitting some limit I don't know about, but can't figure what it is.

Comment: Are you sending HTML mail or plain text?

Comment: It sounds like you should be using PHPMailer (that you tagged this question with) that doesn't need to strip such content from message bodies because it handles them properly. If you hadn't realised, email is fiendishly complicated...

Comment: It's plain text, and it was working fine until I added this latest item. I am using PHPMailer; not sure why I have the string cleaning, if it's not needed, since I'm sure I copied it from elsewhere as I was learning this.